# xslt - for each - line-by-line

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a problem with XSLT pasing with for-each.

```
<publication>
<publicationId>1234</publicationId>
<title>some title</title>
<type>some type</type>
<authors>
<author>author 1</author>
<author>author 2</author>
</authors>
<journal>true</journal>
</publication>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select=publication">
  <xsl:for-each select="authors">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>,
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `for-each-loop` doesn't go line-by-line through the list.

Instead of I also tried but then I only get the first author.

I also would need a "," after every author tag.

Comment: My XML file has a lot of <publiction> .. </publication> tags and I want following output for each <publication>:

first publication:
author1, author2

second publication:
author1, author2, author3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="publication/authors/author">
```

will do the needful. Also when adding "," better to use `<xsl:text>` tag.

Comment: Why is it better to use the `<xsl:text>` tag?

Comment: As per my understanding, <xsl:value-of select="."/>, will display output in two different lines.

Comment: @Kilazur Because then you don't need to worry about indenting your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```
<xsl:for-each select="authors">
```

You should do this

```
<xsl:for-each select="authors/author">
```

This is because there is only one "authors" node, but lots of "author" nodes, and it is the "author" node you want to iterate over.

In fact you could combine the two loops into one, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="publication/authors/author">
```